# ElasticSearch index size with _store.enabled ended up smaller

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm testing with multiple indices of ~16k documents each in 5.1. In one index, I explicitly disabled _source. I expected the index size to be smaller than it's siblings, but instead, it actually increased slightly.

From:`GET source_true,source_false/_stats/docs,store`

```
"indices": {
"source_true": {
  "primaries": {
    "docs": {
      "count": 16079,
      "deleted": 0
    },
    "store": {
      "size_in_bytes": 948662734,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    }
  },
  "total": {
    "docs": {
      "count": 16079,
      "deleted": 0
    },
    "store": {
      "size_in_bytes": 948662734,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    }
  }
},
"source_false": {
  "primaries": {
    "docs": {
      "count": 16000,
      "deleted": 0
    },
    "store": {
      "size_in_bytes": 1039145361,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    }
  },
  "total": {
    "docs": {
      "count": 16000,
      "deleted": 0
    },
    "store": {
      "size_in_bytes": 1039145361,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Is this expected? I double checked that I didnt' change anything else in the mappings. Where else should I hunt for clues?

Comment: It appears the stats I'm seeing are unreliable to begin with. Started a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319897/elasticsearch-stat-size-in-bytes-different-for-identical-indices) to find a resolution.