# ElasticSearch stat size_in_bytes different for identical indices

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, lucene, elasticsearch-5

In ElasticSearch 5.6, I have created multiple indices of the same 15k documents. Specifically, 4 that all share the same mapping, settings, and content.

3 of the 4 had index sizes ~1.0 GB. `index_1` of the 4 has a size of 52 MB. I've compared searches across the 4 indices, and `index_1` returns less documents than the others for identical searches. I've seen anywhere from 1% to 80% less documents per query.

At this point, I don't trust the `docs.count` or the `store.size_in_bytes` on `index_1` or the others. This leaves me in the situation where I'm creating multiple indices just to get a single reliable answer.

Why would one of these indices be so off from the others?

From:`GET index_1, index_2, index_3, index_4/_stats/docs,store`

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 72,
    "successful": 72,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": { // Removed the primaries as they were identical (no replicas)
    "total": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 60000,
        "deleted": 0
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 3276001895,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "indices": {
    "index_1": {
      "total": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 15000,
          "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 54854206, // <-- What is going on here?!?
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "index_2": {
      "total": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 15000,
          "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 1075205322,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "index_3": {
      "total": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 15000,
          "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 1072993635,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "index_4": {
      "total": {
        "docs": {
          "count": 15000,
          "deleted": 0
        },
        "store": {
          "size_in_bytes": 1072948732,
          "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```